# Asynchronous celery task calls in django not getting pushed into rabbitmq queue

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have the celery==3.0.12 and djcelery==3.0.11 installed in my system with django version 1.4.1. I was trying to process some tasks asynchronously using celery in one of my project and it was not working. So for testing I started a new django project, defined the sample task `add` and invoked it from the shell like this

```
 >>>res = add.delay(3, 5)
```

I tried `res.status`, `res.get()` and `res.ready()`, all these are getting blocked. I was monitoring the rabbitmq `celery` queue in the browser using rabbitmq management plugin. The `celery` queue is staying idle and not getting any message.

Following is the directory tree.

```
|-- manage.py
|-- new_app
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tasks.py
|   |-- tasks.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
`-- testapp
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __init__.pyc
    |-- settings.py
    |-- settings.pyc
    |-- urls.py
    `-- wsgi.py
```

Following are the contents of files

new_app/tasks.py

```
from celery import task

@task
def add(x ,y):
    return x + y
```

testapp/settings.py

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = 'guest'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'guest'
BROKER_VHOST = '/'
```

When I am running `python manage.py celeryd -l INFO` , it is creating the `celery` queue.
Following is the console output.
http://dpaste.com/841960/

RabbitMQ version is 3.0.0

Output of `rabbitmqctl list_queues`

```
Listing queues ...
celery  0
h4ckb0x.celery.pidbox   0
...done.
```

Comment: Can you run `rabbitmqctl list_queues` to see if queue and messages are actually created in Rabbit?

Comment: Updated the question with the output of it.

Comment: Could be that you have an old broken worker process running, try `ps auxww | grep celeryd | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`.  You can see if there are any consumers consuming from the queue with `rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers`.  Also those `BROKER_*` settings are unecessary if you have `BROKER_URL` already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare your actions to the following and find what missing in your app:

Configure rabbit:

install it first (ubuntu in our case):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo mkdir /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf.d
```

set user/psw/vhost:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl delete_user guest
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user <username> <password>
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags <username> administrator
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost <some_name_for_vhost>
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p <some_name_for_vhost> <username> ".*" ".*" ".*"')
```

### Define settings:

### settings.py

```
RABBIT_USERNAME = <username>
RABBIT_PASSWORD = <password>
RABBIT_HOST = 'localhost' #or some server dns/ip
RABBIT_VHOST = <some_name_for_vhost>
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://%s:%s@%s:5672/%s' % (RABBIT_USERNAME,RABBIT_PASSWORD,RABBIT_HOST,RABBIT_VHOST)

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

### Define Celery:

### celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourapp.settings')

app = Celery('yourapp')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

### Define tasks:

### tasks.py

```
from celery import task

@task(queue="my_queue")
def do_something_in_background(x1,x2):   
    #start doing something in the task
    #enter you code in here
```

Run the workers:

### (kill nicely all existing, run 10 workers named app_worker, connect them to your task queue: my_queue)

### run_workers.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ps auxww | grep 'yourapp worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
celery -A yourapp worker -Q my_queue -n app_worker -l info -c 10 -Ofair
```

### Define some test:

### test.py

```
import tasks
def my_func():
    tasks.do_something_in_background.delay(x1,x2)
```